# Check array values against other, different sized array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script and thought of using array_intersect but found that apparently it doesn't check against all array values if the array sizes are different.

In my case I have to check the parts of URLs against two arrays, one with domain names, other with specific strings:

```
<?php
$confirm_ref = "http://www.example.com/?x=test&test";
$pp_refz = array_filter(preg_split('(https://|http://|www.|&|=|/|-|\?)', $confirm_ref));

$domains = array("bla.com","bla1.net","bla2.com","bla3.com","bla4.tk","blabla.com","blabla1.com","blabla3.net","example.com");
$strings = array("DIg","AsD","w5L","ptp","ptp.php","hps.php","hide.php","p");

print_r(array_values($pp_refz));

//Check function:
if(array_intersect($pp_refz,$domains,$strings) == true) {
echo "gotcha";
}

?>
```

Even though example.com exists in reference array ($pp_refz), it still doesn't get picked up. Is there any possible workaround for this issue? Or am I missing something here? Any pointers would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can you the output of this line `print_r(array_values($pp_refz));` ?

Comment: Sure: Array ( [0] => example.com [1] => x [2] => test [3] => test )

Comment: array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments.Here no common values  present  in three arrays.So condition goes false.

Comment: "example.com" is present in $domains array....

Comment: yea bt it isnt present on $string array..so "if(array_intersect($pp_refz,$domains,$strings) == true)" intersection of these three returns false

Comment: I see, so it's true only if reference value is present in all arrays. Kind of worthless when you have to check against multiple arrays so better merge them as a workaround as I did.

Comment: Try something like this  - if(array_intersect($pp_refz,$domains) || array_intersect($pp_refz,$strings) ) {

Comment: Yes, that was my previous workaround but I found it to be slower than merging the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured I try merging the two arrays into one, then comparing only the two remaining arrays:

So this is the final, working version:

```
<?php
$confirm_ref = "http://www.example.com/?x=test&test";
$pp_refz = array_filter(preg_split('(https://|http://|www.|&|=|/|-|\?)', $confirm_ref));

$domains = array("bla.com","bla1.net","bla2.com","bla3.com","bla4.tk","blabla.com","blabla1.com","blabla3.net","example.com");
$strings = array("DIg","AsD","w5L","ptp","ptp.php","hps.php","hide.php","p");

//print_r(array_values($pp_refz));

$big = array_merge($domains, $strings);

//print_r(array_values($big));

//Check function:
if(array_intersect($pp_refz,$big) == true) {
echo "gotcha";
}

?>
```

Perhaps someone could explain why it didn't work when comparing against multiple arrays.